# Discrete Random Variables Using PDF

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

For a discrete random variable X with the following pdf find it's expectation.
 X :    -3      4     7   12

p(x) : 0.35  0.25  0.3  0.1

I am trying to study and understand how this problem works so I can apply it on my test on Friday, however I am not sure how to go about this problem. Any help with the answer so I can check my work is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_finite_case). Btw, you are not dealing here with a [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) but with a [pmf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function).

Answer (score 1):

For a discrete distribution, the expectation (average) is given by $$ E(X) = \sum_x x p(x)$$ so in your case it is $$ E(X) = (-3)*0.35+ 4*0.25+7*0.3+12*0.1.$$